# PHP PDO Statement Variable Throwing Syntax Error

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting a very confusing/difficult to figure out syntax error on the following block of code:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS BillCount FROM firms WHERE firm_fk  = ?";
        
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

$stmt->execute();
$billcount = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

The error is in regards to the final line:

```
$billcount = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

And the actual error message is: `syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE)`

Any ideas? This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Try deleting that line and the one before it, and retype it. The PHP syntax looks correct, but there may be an invisible character messing things up.

Comment: Use `var_dump()` also; you'll see for yourself.

Comment: @aynber that was the issue! thank you! So weird... never have to deal with things like this in C#